# Single flags verb agreement

Tags: bug, status-completed, flagging

English has [verb agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agreement_%28linguistics%29#English), where verbs have to agree in grammatical number with their subject. That rule is not being followed on the "Your flagging history" page:

[image: a sad face]

Answer (score 2):

The used phrases have been changed, and now that block appears as in the following screenshot, taken from *English Language & Usage*.

[image: screenshot]

*Are*, and *were* are not used anymore.